# convert an RDD of string into elements of characters using split function

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

Suppose I have an RDD of string as:

```
inputRDD=sc.parallelize('2596,51,3,258,0,510,221,232,148,6279,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5')
```

I want to convert this RDD as:

```
inputRDD= [2596, 51, 3,.....]
```

I implemented the following code:

```
inputRDD.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(',')).collect()
```

But getting output as:

```
['2',
 '5',
 '9',
 '6',
 '',
 '',
 '5',
 '1',
 '',
 '',
 '3',
 '',
 '',
 '2',
 '5',
 '8',
 '',
 '',
 '0',
 '',
 '',
 '5',
 '1',
 '0',
 '',....]
```

May I know where am I going wrong in my code?

Comment: Use inputRDD.map(...) instead of inputRDD.flatMap(...)

Comment: Gives the same output, instead wraps each element of the output in square brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem actually lies in the RDD creation. All you need to do is to wrap the input data in a list for the `parallelize` method, as is here:

```
inputRDD=sc.parallelize(['2596,51,3,258,0,510,221,232,148,6279,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5'])
```

The rest of the code will work fine and as expected afterwards.

What was happening before, is that Spark considered each character as a separate list element, i.e. each character a new row.

Comment: Then one way to overcome this issue is to run this: `inputRDD = sc.parallelize([inputRDD.reduce(lambda x, y: x + y)])` as the first step.